# Which tables/fields reveal user activity in Trac?

Tags: trac

(This may be a webapp question.) I would like to use Trac 1.0.1 activity for time tracking. For example, closing a ticket, editing a wiki page or leaving a comment

I was imagining output something like this:

```
| Time             | Ticket | Custom field | Summary        | Activity                 |
| 2013-05-08 10:00 | 4123   | Acme         | Ticket title   | Ticket closed            |
| 2013-05-08 10:00 | 4200   | Sierra       | Title here     | Comment left on ticket   |
| 2013-05-08 10:00 | -      | -            | -              | Edited /wiki/Acme/Coyote |
| 2013-05-08 10:00 | -      | -            | -              | Committed /git/Apogee.txt|
```

I would like to include basically everything that appears in the timeline, including comment activity. For ticket-related activity, I would like to include ticket number and a custom field.

Which tables should I be looking at? (A pointer to relevant docs or code would suffice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are just asking for trac database schema which can be viewed [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DatabaseSchema), you can also view the source for `timeline` [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/branches/1.0-stable/trac/timeline).

---

[image]

Comment: the schemas on that page are for 0.11 and 0.12, so I was hoping someone who already knew could confirm the fields in 1.0.1, or post a dump of the query used to generate the timeline :D - but thanks, if I get time I'll use this as a reference and confirm if it works in 1.0.1

Comment: If you wanted the query then you should have asked for it not  `What tables should I be looking at? (A pointer to relevant docs or code would suffice.)`. I have added a link to the `timelime` source and the change logs confirm that schema has not changed http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/ChangeLog

Comment: to be clear, I was trying to say that while I ask for the minimum I need, I'm open more to enthusiastic answers :) - I appreciate the confirmation, thanks very much